# Java static attributes in an abstract class

Tags: java, static, attributes, abstract

I want to set the name and the code static attributes in the milk class.
Why doesn't this work?
I can't even override the setters/getters of the name and the code.

```
    public abstract class Cow {
        private static String name;
        private static String code;

    ...
     public static String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public static void setName(String name) {
            Cow.name = name;
        }

        public static String getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public static void setCode(String code) {
            Cow.code = code;
        }
    ...
    }

public class Milk extends Cow{

...
    static {
            Milk.setName("asdmilk");
        Milk.setCode("KDDFA");
        }
..

}
```

Comment: Those should probably be instance variables (that is, not `static`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why doesn't this work?

You don't get one set of static variables per subclass of `Cow`, and you can't override static methods at all. Static members aren't polymorphic, basically.

It's not clear *why* you're trying to do this, but basically if you declare a static variable, there's *one* variable, full stop. Calling `Milk.setName` is exactly equivalent to calling `Cow.setName` here.

Answer (score 1):

The static methods setName and setCode live in Cow, not in Milk.  You should say

```
public class Milk extends Cow{

...
static {
        Cow.setName("asdmilk");
        Cow.setCode("KDDFA");
    }
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You change static getters and setters to normal getters, setters. But keep the variabls as static.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit and than overide static methods - please, remember that static method are for classes (they only live in the original class)., they do not operate on any object as such (you can explicitly reference an object in the arguments though). They're not able to be use polymorphism.

Also method overiding is determined at compile than, overloading is determined at runtime.

Although you can keep he static fields as javac deems to them to be 'constants' or constant: They do not change throughout your programs life (you can judge this more easily with the final modifier).

Private fields are also not inherited.

Comment: I thought when the milk class was made It's got an own static name and a static code for its own class which don't belong to the cow.

Comment: You cannot inherit static method full stop.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you have a class `Milk` which extends `Cow`. Normally the `extends` keyword represents a *type of* relationship. For example, `Poodle extends Dog` since a Poodle is a type of Dog. Milk is not a type of Cow.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `static` variables are `One per Class`, which is shared by all the objects.

**-** Moreover `static` members are **not polymorphic**, and just to remind you `private` variables are **not inherited**.

**-** So you **canNot** override the static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not inherited, so they have to be referenced in the superclass. The only way to get the name and codes to be different for all subclasses is to have the subclasses define them themselves. I recommend that you stay away from declaring static state for hierarchical structures completely instead of trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve what you want using this idea:

```
public abstract class Cow {

protected static HashMap<String, String> names;
protected static HashMap<String, String> codes;

//...

     public static String getName(String key) {
            return (String) names.get(key);
        }

        public static void setName(String key, String name) {
            names.put(key, name);
        }

        public static String getCode(String key) {
            return (String) codes.get(key);
        }

        public static void setCode(String code) {
            codes.put(key, name);
        }

        protected void initialize()
        {
            setName("Cow", "foo");
            setCode("Cow", "bar");
        }

        protected static void initializeClass()
        {
            initialize();
        }
}

public class Milk extends Cow {
    protected void initialize()
    {
        setName("asdmilk");
        setCode("KDDFA");
    }
}
```